# General route interceptors for react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, refluxjs

Once a user logs in, they cannot continue until they complete their profile. If a user tries to navigate to a different page, I want to intercept them and redirect them back to the profile page as long as their profile is complete. Currently the best solution I came up with is:

```
render() {
  if (!profileComplete()) {
    return document.location.assign(document.location.origin + '/complete-prof'));
  }
  return <Page />;
}
```

While this does work, it seems incorrect in that you are supposed to return a valid component from `render`.

I have also tried doing this in `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount`. This also works, but then you can see a flash of the other page get rendered before the redirect occurs.

This is a minor point but I also have to include this intercept on all pages that need to be intercepted rather than handle it through some configuration or a more generalized method.

Is there a preferred method for blocking/intercepting routes when using React views?

Answer (score 1):

How about this [Lifecycle Mixin](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/API.md#lifecycle-mixin)

the routerWillLeave method can block the route

but if you want to redirect at outside of the profile component when user want to enter other pages, you may need to add an onEnter in the <Route> tag:  [onEnter of Route](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/API.md#route)

```
// check login 
function auth(next, replace) {
    let isLogin = Auth.isLogin();
    if (next.location.pathname === '/login' && isLogin) {
        replace(null, '/');
    } else if (next.location.pathname !== '/login' && !isLogin) {
        replace(null, '/login');
    }
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    ReactDOM.render((
        <Router onUpdate={onPathChange} history={history}>
            <Route path='/' component={App} onEnter={auth}>
                <IndexRedirect to='index' />
                <Route path='index' component={Index} />
                <Route path="category" component={Category} />
                <Route path="attribute" component={Attribute} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='login' component={Login} onEnter={auth} />
        </Router>),
      appElement
    );
});
```

Comment: The Lifecycle mixin is deprecated, so I'd rather not use it. Mixins in general seem to be frowned up on in React. Can you tell me more of what you mean about `redirect at outside of the profile component`?

Comment: I mean setting redirection in route config, like the code above, it is a check login redirect.  Add onEnter to the route which you want redirect when profile uncompleted. If you want to do this, you have to check profile completion outside components.